# mysql views performance vs extra column

Tags: mysql, performance, join, view

my question is about selecting the best method to perform a job. i'll present the goal and my various solutions.

i have a list of items and a list of categories. each can belong to a number of categories.

```
items          (id, name, ...other fields...)
categories     (id, name, ...... )
category_items (category_id, item_id)
```

the items list is very large and is updated every 10 minutes (using cron). the categories list is fixed.

on my page, i'm showing a large list of items and i have category filters. the whole filtering is done on client side javascript. The reason is that the items that are currently available are limited to +- 1000, so all the data (items+categories) will be loaded together.

this page is about to be viewed many times, so performance is an issue here. I have several ideas, both will result in a good performance. in all of them, the complete list of categories will be sent. the items however...

1. running a single select using join and group_concat. something like this:

   > SELECT i.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ci.`category_id` SEPARATOR ",") AS category_list
   >       FROM `items` AS i
   >       LEFT JOIN `category_items` AS ci ON (ci.`item_id` = i.`id`)
   >       WHERE ... GROUP BY i.`id` ORDER BY ...
2. creating a view with the above
3. storing the GROUP_CONCAT result as an additional column. this will only be updated every several minutes under cron.

indexing is done correctly so all methods will work relatively fast. join is a heavy operation, so my question is about (2), (3):

is the view updated only on every CRUD or is it calculated on every select? if it is only updated on CRUD, it should be about the same as storing the column.

take in mind that the items table will grow, and only latest rows will be selected.

Comment: It depends - you'll have to test for yourself, over time as the number of rows involved increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 4. Have a `MEMORY` type table, which will be updated with results of your query from solution 1, by the same cron script, that updates `items` table.

Other than that: 1. and 2. are equivalent. MySQL's views are not materialised, so querying the view will actually run the `SELECT` from point 1.

Comment: from what i understand, memory table will be the same as solution 3 (extra column) when it comes to performance, only space will be saved up, since the group_concat will be stored only for the latest (selected) results. is that correct?

Comment: `MEMORY` would be faster just because it's always stored in RAM (assuming there's enough of it available on the server), while your usual `MyISAM`/`InnoDB` tables are stored on disk. It can also use `HASH` type indexes, which are very fast for `=` comaprisons (but not so for `LIKE`)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a view is just saving a query, (2) will still run the query and the join.  (3) of course will save the time at the expense of space.

The answer, therefore is a question:  Do *you* and *your app* value time or space?

Also, instead of using cron to update the cache field (your GROUP_CONCAT) you could use a trigger on the category_items table;

Comment: it's a relatively small amount of space (especially since i save the id's alone).